# check valve in hot water loop held open by salts or crytals

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

I have a pressurised (UK spelling) hot water loop which back-flows at night, cooling the tank and costing me money. Years ago I fitted a check valve to check the night-flow opposite to the circulation pump and this gave some improvement. I have replaced the valve a few times as the plastic parts don't wear well in the hot water flow.

Recently I fitted a new 22mm check valve and altered my pipework to enable quick removal for checking. After the new valve was fitted I got the improved hot water retention for a few nights but then noticed it had started to cool again.

I removed the check valve and found it was held open by white crystals, which I removed. One day later I re-inspected, and they have appeared again.

We do not live in a hard water area.

My questions are:

What could they be, if not calcium?

Would a Y strainer be an option or are the crystals probably building up in flow?

Any similar experience and what was the solution?

[image: internal shot of 22mm check valve, 24 hour deposits]

Comment: Assuming you are in a reticulate area, tap water is not soft.  I would get a spa/pool test strip and check the PH, hardness etc of the water **first**.  Can you see this in any other tap/valve assembly ?

Comment: Are the "white crystals" the white band from 3:00 to 6:00, or is it the blob of goop at 6 o'clock and 8 o'clock and 12 o'clock?

Comment: You might want a valveless heat trap, (deep u-bend of pipe to prevent thermo-syphoning)  but I'd certainly give a strainer/filter (hot water rated) a try.

Comment: @RohI am in Yorkshire UK, a notoriously soft water area. If I can get a pH strip I will check though.

Comment: @FreeMan,  they are all the same, a crystal which crushes under fingernail. Next time I harvest some I will see if they are soluble in cold or hot water.

Comment: Interesting. The two different objects I noted look _very_ different and the blobs look very much like a gel, not crystalline at all. However, I'll trust you on it, as you're there to touch/feel it and I'm not.